# Designing complex workflow with specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

Developing functional tests i need to simulate a workflow with result of one step being used as an input for the following one(s). Example is like this:

1. search for a hotel\room with given criteria

   - check that request succeeded
   - check that there are at least some results
2. pick random room from step 1.
3. book the room from step 2.

   - check that request succeeded
4. cancel the booking from step 3.

   - check that request succeeded

Key points here are:

- we cannot perform 3. without doing 1.
- we cannot perform 4. without doing 3.
- if a step fails, we should abort the feature

What is the approach to developing a specification for such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to have a mutable object representing the process and a `sequential` Specification:

```
class HotelSpec extends mutable.Specification { sequential
  val hotel = new HotelProcess

  "get a room available on Monday" >> ifHotelOk {
    val rooms = request(MONDAY)
    hotel.selectedRooms = rooms
    rooms must not beEmpty
  }

  "book the room" >> ifHotelOk {
    val booking = bookRoom(hotel.selectedRooms.head)
    hotel.currentBooking = booking
    booking must beOk
  }

  def ifHotelOk(r: =>Any) = if (hotel.canContinueProcess) {
    try { r; hotel.continueProcess }
    catch { case t: Throwable => hotel.stopProcess; throw t }
  } else skipped("hotel process error in previous steps")
}
```

[UPDATE]

Here is another way to do it where the var is better encapsulated:

```
import org.specs2._
import org.specs2.execute._
import org.specs2.specification.FixtureExample

class HotelSpec extends HotelProcessSpec {
  "get a room available on Monday" >> { hotel: HP =>
    val rooms = request(MONDAY)
    rooms must be empty

    // update the state of the process at the end of the example
    hotel.selectedRoomsAre(rooms)
  }

  // this example will only execute if the previous step was ok
  "book the room" >> { hotel: HP =>
    val booking = bookRoom(hotel.selectedRooms.head)
    booking.booked must beTrue
  }

  val MONDAY = "monday"
  def request(day: String): Seq[Room] = Seq(Room())
  def bookRoom(room: Room) = Booking()
}

/**
 * A specification trait encapsulating the process of booking hotel rooms
 */
trait HotelProcessSpec extends mutable.Specification with FixtureExample[HotelProcess] {
  sequential

  type HP = HotelProcess
  private var hotelProcess = HotelProcess()

  // if the hotelProcess is returned as the last statement of an Example
  // set the new value of the hotelProcess and return Success
  implicit def hotelProcessAsResult: AsResult[HotelProcess] = new AsResult[HotelProcess] {
    def asResult(hp: =>HotelProcess) =
      try { hotelProcess = hp; Success() }
      catch { case t: Throwable => hotelProcess = hotelProcess.stop; throw t }
  }

  /**
   * stop executing examples if one previous step failed
   */
  protected def fixture[R : AsResult](f: HotelProcess => R): Result = {
    if (hotelProcess.continue) {
      val result = AsResult(f(hotelProcess))
      if (!result.isSuccess) hotelProcess = hotelProcess.stop
      result
    }
    else                       skipped(" - SKIPPED: can't execute this step")
  }

}

case class HotelProcess(selectedRooms: Seq[Room] = Seq(), continue: Boolean = true) {
  def stop = copy(continue = false)
  def selectedRoomsAre(rooms: Seq[Room]) = copy(selectedRooms = rooms)
}
case class Room(number: Int = 0)
case class Booking(booked: Boolean = true)
```

Comment: I think that it should be possible to encapsulate this with a `Fixture` to avoid mutable State, I'll try that later on.

Comment: thank you for great example! it took me a while to realise it, but after all i was correct in thinking about necessity of holding a mutable state.
thank you for great support and very interesting lib!